# How to php echo content into <div> classes dynamicaly

Tags: php, html, css, background-image, echo

My goal is to print all results (fetched from database) and print it according to respective formation.

In html, I could defined it as follows:

```
<div class="gallery-item category-birds">
<div class="gallery-item-image" style="background-image: url( '_uploads/bc7113a3956b7a45e926f30258fa1b83.jpg' );">
<div class="gallery-item-image-pattern">
<span>Show image</span>
</div>
</div>
<h3>ImageTest1</h3>
<p>MyImageDescription.</p>
</div>
```

In php, I am trying to print the results in a loop (like I have done before in others examples) but for some reason it's not working.

**"animals.php"**

```
<?php
include("../config.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE catid=2 ORDER BY id DESC",$connect);

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))          
{//begin of loop
echo "<div class='gallery-item category-birds'>";
echo "<div class=gallery-item-image style='background-image:url(_uploads/bc7113a3956b7a45e926f30258fa1b83.jpg);'>";
echo "<div class=gallery-item-image-pattern>";         
echo "<span>Show image</span>";            
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<h3> ".$myrow['name']." </h3>";
echo "<p> ".$myrow['description']." </p>";
echo "</div>";          
}//end of loop  
?>
```

The index.php includes "**animals.php**".
The database connection is fine, because by accessing `"animals.php"` I have the content desired.
The `index.php` have css linked, where is defined the classes and others.

I have tried to replace inside of those echo's: **" for \"**. -> Not working.
I have tried to replace inside of those echo's: **" for '**. -> Not working.

Could you help me? Iam out of ideas how to solve this.

Thanks and regards,
RMC

Comment: First turn on `display_errors` in your `php.ini` and `restart apache` so that u get proper errors displayed on page. Second, ensure your db query is returning values so that there is some thing to loop over.

Comment: *what* is not working ?

Comment: And you are missing apostrophes on 2 of your div's class attributes

Comment: First of all check the syntax                       mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE catid=2 ORDER BY id DESC",$connect); whether you need $connect it is not required as you are using PHP4+ something i guess remove it and check out

Comment: Either turn on errors as per @mithunsatheesh's comment, or do something like `include() or die("<message>");`, `mysql_query() or die("<message>");`. Also **`mysql*` functions are DEPRICATED. Dont use them. Use `mysqli*` functions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst there is no issue with the MySQL if you can access the page and it works. The issue is when you include it in another page. The issue that comes to mind is if *animals.php* is located in a folder, example: /inc/. Your *config.php* and *index.php* are located in your docroot(/). This may cause a relative issue in loading the *config.php* file, because it may be looking out of your docroot. I would check your error.log on your server to verify this. I normally in any templated PHP website that I have created, my *config.php* file would be included in *index.php* since it would be used by the whole site.

A few potential solutions:

- check your error.log to make sure it is finding the *config.php* file in the right location
- move your include for *config.php* to index.php
- read up on php templating, example tutorial - http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Thanks, you've made my day!! 

It was because the include. 
The animals.php is inside "/root/folder" and the config.php was inside "root", for example. I've move everything to the samme folder and that magically started to worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some single quotes around your class name of div 2 and 3

```
<?php
include("../config.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE catid=2 ORDER BY id DESC",$connect);

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))          
{//begin of loop
echo "<div class='gallery-item category-birds'>";
echo "<div class='gallery-item-image' style='background-image:url(_uploads/bc7113a3956b7a45e926f30258fa1b83.jpg);'>";
echo "<div class='gallery-item-image-pattern'>";         
echo "<span>Show image</span>";            
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<h3> ".$myrow['name']." </h3>";
echo "<p> ".$myrow['description']." </p>";
echo "</div>";          
}//end of loop  
?>
```

(P.s. I also assume that you make your connection with the database in your config.php file, 
what makes that you don't need to put your `$connect` variable in the `mysql_query()` function.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE catid=2 ORDER BY id DESC");

)